# Text Alignment in columns like newspapers (XAML)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-8

I need to create some xaml that shows text in columns like newspaper, something like this:
[image]

is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Silverlight 5 which allows Text to overflow from one TextBox and flow into another.

[http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/what's-new-in-silverlight-5/silverlight-5-multi-column-and-linked-text](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/overview/what%27s-new-in-silverlight-5/silverlight-5-multi-column-and-linked-text)

Comment: wow, thanks a lot. that would be easy now. do you know if they have something similar for winrt (windows 8 metro apps)?

Comment: sorry, I didnt notice its already there also for winrt. Thanks a lot.